# Marin's weird fender bolt hole direction

Tags: fenders

The bolt hole is facing the fender on my Marin Presidio 3. Why have Marin done this and what are the solutions?

[image: Back Fender]

Comment: So there is a hole on the underside of the seat stay bridge, facing the wheel? Does it actually have threads? Apparently on some bikes the fenders are mounted this way: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-919drTbtp7g/WoMMVZk_G3I/AAAAAAAATbA/jWT4K7w1BLsnIAt1WOoEpwSRgnKrzmz8QCLcBGAs/s1600/PHD%2Bseat%2Bstays%2Bdropped%2Bout%2Bfinal.jpg I guess you could drill a hole through the fender and do the same (use wide washers to spread the load).

Comment: This is quite a common way to attach mudguards, just drill where you need the hole to be. Mudguard mfcturers often give some instructions on this.

Comment: If this is the planet bike rear fender, trust me, the plastic clip is solid. Put the zip ties through those two little holes/slots and around the seat stay bridge. It’ll hold.

Comment: So this question is not about the zip ties?

Comment: Can you please add more info with [edit]  ?  There's no indication of where your bolt hole is in the photo.

Answer (score 5):

Already mentioned in a comment, but in my opinion worth an answer:

The fender is installed by drilling or punching a hole through the fender and putting a screw through the fender and the hole in seatstay bridge. Use washers to adjust the position and spread the load.

The benefits of this setup are tighter connection with less rattling and loose parts compared to the clip shown in the photo, simpler assembly and compared to the setup with clip built into the fender, the same fender fits all bikes with same tire size.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go to the effort of drilling the bridge (or you lack the tools to do so), you can likely install this rack using a P-clamp:

[image]

They come in a variety of sizes, so you can pick one that fits around your bridge and put the a bolt through that.  Just to pick a random example from Google, without recommendation since I've never dealt with them, [here is a store that sells a range of sizes for attaching bike racks and fenders](https://velo-orange.com/products/p-clamps-for-fender-attachment).

Comment: Why would the OP need to drill the bridge? The question says there already is a hole.

Comment: @ojs I got "drilling" from your answer; I see now you're talking about the fender, but I didn't read it that way because it didn't make sense to me.